# How to use format function for following statement

Tags: python, string

```
assert "hello his" == simple_format("hello %0", "his")
```

I want to write a function called `simple_format` for the above statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). `str.format` accept `{0}`, `{1}`, ... instead of `%0`, `%1`; need to convert them. I used [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) in the following code:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> def simple_format(fmt, *args):
...     fmt = re.sub(r'%(\d+)', r'{\1}', fmt)  # %0 -> {0}
...     return fmt.format(*args)
...
>>> simple_format("hello %0", "his")
'hello his'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you could make this assert work. Though using a format method would look like the following.

```
assert "hello his"  == "hello {0}".format("his")
```